# Expected value of picking smallest k random variables out of n

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The question is,
I'm picking random variables from a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. If I'm picking n random variables and sorting them in the ascending order, what is the expected value of first k variables (from the sorted n variables)? Can anyone help me to derive an expression for this expected value?

Comment: Useful keyphrase: "Order statistics"

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this? This question is part of my research and I would like to see some comments for any methods which I can try.